# split a string after "numberx word"

Tags: php, regex, explode

I want to split a string like this:

```
1x cola => 1x & cola
12x sprite => 12x & sprite
spaghetti => spaghetti
```

So the logic is that i want to split it after a "number times" if it is in the string. Explode would work well if every line would have the "number times" in front of the actual product.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use a regular expression with an optional pattern to match number followed by x.

Comment: I got it using preg_split('/[0-9]{1,2}+x/')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) helps you.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    '1x cola',
    '12x sprite',
    'spaghetti',
);

foreach ($arr as $string){
    preg_match('/^((?P<count>[0-9]+x)\s{1})?(?P<item>.+)$/', $string, $matches);
    if(!empty($matches['count'])){
        // do something
    }
    if(!empty($matches['item'])){
        // do something
    }
}
```